# What is the server URL to be used while adding bitbucket token in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

I have generated a [API token](https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens) and trying to add in android studio

- File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub

[image]

I tried below server URL's but non of them are working for me

- https://bitbucket.org/
- bitbucket.org
- https://bitbucket.org
- https://id.atlassian.com/
- id.atlassian.com

What is the exact server URL i should be using while adding the bitbucket token to android studio?

Answer (score 0):

1. create app password for your repository of bitbucket
2. open terminal

   - git config --global credential.helper store
   - git pull
   - save your id and password
3. File -> Settings -> Version Contol -> Git -> Checking "Use credential helper"

Good luck!